# Как сделать чтобы AutoSlugField в Django работал с кириллицей?

Tags: python, django, slug

У меня есть поле в модели:

```
slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='title', unique=True, db_index=True)
```

Если у меня в title текст кириллицей то выдает ошибку, если написано буквами английского алфавита, то все ок, все работает. 
Как сделать чтобы slug работал и с кириллицей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно поставить вот этот пакет https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pytils . Тогда django будет работать и с кириллицей. Если в заголовке(title) будет кириллицей, то в slug запишется транслит этого заголовка.